# Where is the default docker image registry when just image name is specified in a manifest?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

When my yaml is something like this :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: task-pv-pod
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: task-pv-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: task-pv-claim
  containers:
    - name: task-pv-container
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: "http-server"
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
          name: task-pv-storage
```

Where is the nginx image coming from? for e.g. in GKE Kubernetes world, if I was going to reference an image from registry it's normally something like this:

```
image: gsr.io.foo/nginx
```

but in this case it's just an image name:

```
image: nginx
```

So trying to just understand where the source registry is on when deployed on a K8 cluster as it seems to pull down ok but just want to know how I can figure out where it's supposed to come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I was able to specifically confirm from my node based on the container runtime:

1. If your nodepool is running docker, you may run `docker system info` and look for the image being pulled from `mirror.gcr.io`.
2. If your nodepool is running containerd, you may run `sudo crictl info` and look for the same as above.

Answer (score 3):

It's coming from docker hub (https://hub.docker.com/) when only image name is specified in the manifest file. Example:

```
...
Containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
...
```

For nginx, it's coming from official nginx repository (https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx).

Comment: See I thought that would be the case but then this particular cluster and nodes are all on a PVC which should have no access to any external access such as (https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx.I just can't see how that would work in this case?

Comment: Normally kubernetes pods can pull Docker images directly when a deployment takes place. Pods always run in a node. I don't understand the pvc part here. Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: I meant it's in vpc (not pvc) so has no external access outside

Comment: In those cases, private container registries like aws ECR (which under the same vpc and security group) are the only option, I think.

Comment: that would make sense, so any ideas what private registry url it would use?
is there anyway to check the source of the image, just seems a bit mysterious